# Add VERSION_INFO to jar

Tags: spring-boot, spring-boot-maven-plugin

How to add VERSION_INFO meta data to jar with spring boot ?

I have seen the plugin

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
</plugin>
```

with the execution "repackage" but I cannot add this meta_data in my executable jar file.

Answer (score 0):

Do you really need the version in `META-INF/MANIFEST.MF`?

If you add these placeholders to **application.yml** properties file:

```
# app name and build version updated during build process from Maven properties.
info:
  app:
    name: @project.artifactId@
  build:
    version: @project.version@
```

They get replaced while building the artifact and available when sending a `GET` request to `/info` `actuator` endpoint, for instance:

```
curl "http://localhost:8080/info"
{"app":{"name":"demo-cxf"},"build":{"version":"0-SNAPSHOT"}}
```